# how to use `if case` statement as boolean in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this enum (with associated type)

```
enum CookieType {
  case regular(type: Int)
  case gem(type: GemType)
}

struct Cookie {
  let type: CookieType
  let otherStuff...
}
```

Now if i want to do pattern matching, i can do this with no problem:

```
if case .gem == cookie.type {

}
```

However, I want to use `case .gem == cookie.type` as a boolean. The following gives error

```
  var cookies: [Cookie] {
    return [cookieA, cookieB]
  }
  
  var gems: [Cookie] {
    return cookies.filter { case $0.type == .gem } // this has error
  }
```

which means `case $0.type == .gem` is not a boolean. How can I deal with this?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-sanity-check-assigning-a-case-statement-to-a-boolean/40584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case .gem = cookie.type` is not a boolean expression, and `if` statements not only accept boolean expressions. However, in the closure argument for `filter`, you must write an `Bool` expression or a block that returns `Bool`.

One way to do that is:

```
cookies.filter { 
    if case $0.type = .gem { return true }
    else { return false }
}
```

Or, you can add convenient properties to `CookieType` that gives you `Bool` values, if you tend to do this a lot:

```
enum CookieType {
  case regular(type: Int)
  case gem(type: GemType)

  var isRegular: Bool {
    if case .regular = self { return true }
    else { return false }
  }

  var isGem: Bool {
    if case .gem = self { return true }
    else { return false }
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
cookies.filter(\.isGem)
```

Comment: Nice! Still it feels like there is a slight “hole” in the Swift language here...

Comment: There are libraries like EnumKit and CasePaths that can help, agree this could be a future language feature

Comment: It's just a missing operator; see my answer. It looks like EnumKit expands on the idea, but gets the operand order backwards. https://github.com/gringoireDM/EnumKit/blob/master/Tests/EnumKitTests/CaseAccessibleMatchingTests.swift

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `if case` and `switch` statements [are abstractions based on the pattern matching operator ~=](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html), but that's not how enums with associated types are implemented. As such, for the time being, you need to reverse-engineer how it might have been done, to allow this:

```swift
cookies.filter { CookieType.regular ~= $0.type }
```

I do not believe it is possible to avoid the explicit `CookieType` there, but it still reads better than all alternatives.

```swift
/// Match `enum` cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// - Parameter case: Looks like `Enum.case`.
public func ~= <Enum, AssociatedValue>(
  case: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,
  instance: Enum
) -> Bool {
  Mirror.associatedValue(of: instance, ifCase: `case`) != nil
}
```

```swift
public extension Mirror {
  /// Get an `enum` case's `associatedValue`.
  static func associatedValue<AssociatedValue>(
    of subject: Any,
    _: AssociatedValue.Type = AssociatedValue.self
  ) -> AssociatedValue? {
    guard let childValue = Self(reflecting: subject).children.first?.value
    else { return nil }

    if let associatedValue = childValue as? AssociatedValue {
      return associatedValue
    }

    let labeledAssociatedValue = Self(reflecting: childValue).children.first
    return labeledAssociatedValue?.value as? AssociatedValue
  }

  /// Get an `enum` case's `associatedValue`.
  /// - Parameter case: Looks like `Enum.case`.
  static func associatedValue<Enum, AssociatedValue>(
    of instance: Enum,
    ifCase case: (AssociatedValue) throws -> Enum
  ) rethrows -> AssociatedValue? {
    try associatedValue(of: instance).filter {
      .equate(try `case`($0), to: instance) {
        Self(reflecting: $0).children.first?.label
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Transform `.some` into `.none`, if a condition fails.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - isSome: The condition that will result in `nil`, when evaluated to `false`.
  func filter(_ isSome: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self {
    try flatMap { try isSome($0) ? $0 : nil }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Equatable {
  /// Equate two values using a closure.
   static func equate<Wrapped, Equatable: Swift.Equatable>(
    _ optional0: Wrapped?, to optional1: Wrapped?,
    using transform: (Wrapped) throws -> Equatable
  ) rethrows -> Bool {
    try optional0.map(transform) == optional1.map(transform)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does relying on the reflection mean if we build the app for production with certain meta data disabled or obfuscated, this will fail?

Comment: I haven't heard of that; I don't think it's possible. If you can find out a way to break it though, I'd love to know about it!

Comment: iirc i had a crash in production only (with STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS enabled). And it turned out that my code relied on something related to mirror. That was a couple years ago

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Jessy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652038/jessy) and [SwiftLee](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/reflection-how-mirror-works/), here is my solution:

```
// -----------------------
//     CaseReflectable
// -----------------------

// designed for enums only 
// (use it on other types not recommended)
protocol CaseReflectable {}

// default behaviors.
extension CaseReflectable {
    
    /// case name
    var caseName: String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        // enum cases:
        // - normal case: no children
        // - case with associated values: one child (with label)
        guard let label = mirror.children.first?.label else {
            return "\(self)"    // normal case
        }
        // case with associated values
        return label
    }
    
    /// associated values
    var associatedValues: Any? {
        
        // if no children, a normal case, no associated values.
        guard let firstChild = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return firstChild.value
    }
}

// --------------------------
//     custom operator ~=
// --------------------------

/// match enum cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// usage: `Enum.enumCase ~= instance`
func ~= <Enum: CaseReflectable, AssociatedValue>(
    // an enum case (with associated values)
    enumCase: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,    // enum case as function
    // an instance of Enum
    instance: Enum
) -> Bool 
{
    // if no associated values, `instance` can't be of `enumCase`
    guard let values = instance.associatedValues else { return false }
    // if associated values not of the same type, return false
    guard values is AssociatedValue else { return false }
    // create an instance from `enumCase` (as function)
    let case2 = enumCase(values as! AssociatedValue)
    // if same case name, return true
    return case2.caseName == instance.caseName
}

// ------------
//     Enum
// ------------

// enum with associated values
// (conforms to `CaseReflectable`)
enum Enum: CaseReflectable {
    case int(Int)
    case int2(Int)
    case person(name: String, age: Int)
    case str(String)
}

// ------------
//     main
// ------------

let a: Enum = .int(3)

Enum.int ~= a        // true
Enum.int2 ~= a       // false

let joe = Enum.person(name: "joe", age: 8)

Enum.person ~= joe   // true
Enum.int ~= joe      // false

// array of enum cases
let items: [Enum] = [
    .int(1), .str("hi"), .int(2)
]

// filter enum cases
let filtered = items.filter { Enum.int ~= $0 }
print(filtered)      // [Enum.int(1), Enum.int(2)]
```